# Python: how to sum binaries? From binary-power-vector presentation to real binary presentation, how?

Tags: python, math, syntax, binary

I am trying to express a list that express a binary number as a real binary number like (1,3,6) means `0b100101`. First, I try to sum them as 2^1+2^3+2^6 and then convert to binary

```
with open('DATA.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
            myLine=line.rstrip().split("\t")
            print [bin(2**int(l)) for l in myLine[1:5]]
```

where I converted it to list like the `a` below so

```
>>> a=['0b10000000000000000000000000', '0b100000000000', '0b100000000000000000000000000000']
>>> a[1]|a[2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
>>> bin(a[1])+bin(a[2])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an index
```

So

> **How should I convert the power vector into a binary number i.e. how can I get from power-binary number presentation into real binary number presentation?**

**Simple example**

> **Input**
>
> ```
> ['0b10000000000000000000000000', '0b100000000000', '0b100000000000000000000000000000']
> ```
>
> **Intended Output**
>
> ```
> 0b100010000000000000100000000000
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bakuriu explained what is going on very well, so I’ll make this short. The solution to your problem is

```
with open('DATA.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        myLine=line.rstrip().split("\t")
        print sum(2**int(l) for l in myLine[1:5])
```

Note that summation is equal to binary or, as long as only different bits are set, which I assume is the case here.

Comment: I get binary numbers of different lengths, is it possible to get every number in certain length such as 10-int-long? Example: "0b10 0b1100 0b100100 0b11000" so that "0b00010 0b001100 0b100100 0b011000" where extra zeros padded to the front? someStringBinary.zfill(30) works almost like that.

Comment: `"0b"+bin(20)[2:].zfill(10)`

Answer (score 2):

The value returned by the [`bin`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin) built-in is a simple *string*. It's not a "binary number". Binary numbers do not exist, there is only a binary *representation* of numbers. Python integers are internally represented as base-2, the `bin` function allow to "see" this(actually the modulus and sign representation, not two's complement) representation as a string.

If you want to perform bitwise operations such as `|` on those strings  you must convert them to integers and then back to strings:

```
In [7]: bin(int('0b10000', 2)|int('0b100', 2))
Out[7]: '0b10100'
```

If, given a list of binary strings, you want to obtain a number that combines those strings you can use the [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.reduce) function:

```
In [8]: import operator as op

In [9]: from functools import reduce

In [10]: a = ['0b10000000000000000000000000', '0b100000000000', '0b100000000000000000000000000000']

In [13]: bin(reduce(op.or_, (int(num, 2) for num in a)))
Out[13]: '0b100010000000000000100000000000'
```